# Is it possible to make custom "no internet connection" error page using CI / JavaScript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

As the title said, I would like to create my own custom error page when there is no internet connection. Is it possible to do this using CI / JavaScript / PHP ? and how if it is possible. I have researched and it seems that it can only be done in java webapp.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this without having access to the O/S, which JavaScript doesn't have when it runs in the browser.

Comment: but if there is no internet connection the user can't access your webserver.

Comment: Learn about Javascript ServiceWorker  that might help  you ... Concept of ServiceWorker is Offline First

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Thanks @MASIDDIQUI Will be looking into it

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for the link, going to read on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but at least one time users must have the internet connection, so that all the assets downloaded and next time service worker will take care of no internet page.

Check https://link.medium.com/xu2cVcvV6xb