# Is possible to show default content while no internet access in html page by using html/html5?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

need to show the predefined HTML page / HTML content while no internet access in the web page by using HTML alone.

Comment: You need to download it, and view it as a file on your machine.

Comment: Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797118/is-it-possible-to-make-custom-no-internet-connection-error-page-using-ci-jav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(navigator.onLine) { // true|false
    // ...
}
```

and then if the user is offline, show them another piece of content:

```
function showOnlineContent() {
    var onlineContent = document.getElementById('onlineContent');
    onlineContent.style.display = 'block';
}

function showOfflineContent() {
    var offlineContent = document.getElementById('offlineContent');
    offlineContent.style.display = 'block';
}

// Update the content based on connectivity
window.addEventListener('online',  showOnlineContent);
window.addEventListener('offline', showOfflineContent);
```

You may want to combine the event listeners to the same handler and check for the status of connectively in there and toggle the content.

Alternative approach is to use an app manifest that PWA's use: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2010-06-18:v3

# Explicitly cached entries
index.html
css/style.css

# offline.html will be displayed if the user is offline
FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html

# All other resources (e.g. sites) require the user to be online. 
NETWORK:
*

# Additional resources to cache
CACHE:
images/logo1.png
images/logo2.png
images/logo3.png
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  we can achieve by navigation.onLine using the js. But I want to know, any possible ways to achieve by HTML/HTML5/meta tag apart from any scripts.

Comment: updated answer with a PWA (progressive web app) approach that uses an app manifest.

Comment: wow.... I got it. thanks a lot @steve. :-)